# How to convert ZBRUSH .ZBP to a .jpeg or .png that I can use in blender sculping

Tags: transparency, texture-painting, zbrush

I bought a $20 texture scale alpha for my dinosaur modelling https://www.artstation.com/marketplace/p/mjq6/28-custom-brushes-for-zbrush-2018?utm_source=artstation&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=homepage&utm_term=marketplace

and it's only zbrush compatible. The owner is not responding for a refund. It has .ZBP file extension and I simply want to convert it to .png or .jpeg so I can use it as a stencil in blender sculpting.

Comment: did you get your refund?

Answer (score -1):

If you can open up ZBP files to view it in a photo viewer( I have no experience with ZBP), then you, if you are using windows, can take the snipping tool in windows accessories and take a snip of it. It will be either a PNG or JPEG, I'm not sure, but it sounds like you are okay with both. If you are using an apple product, Control+Shift+4 will allow you to take a snip.

Comment: Usually these brushes have an alpha channel which will not get carried over by this method